# Wysiwyg (ckeditor) disappeared after drush rr

Tags: drush, wysiwyg

I was restructuring the modules directory (moving modules from /sites/all/modules/ to /sites/default/modules/) because we are adding a multi-site and do not want to share all the modules.  After moving them I ran `drush rr` in the /sites/default/ directory and then `drush cc all` for good measure.

Everything went fine except that now on all of the content editor forms the rich text editors are all gone.  I can click "switch to plain text editor" and it works fine, but CKEditor is now completely gone.

I tried doing `drush pmu ckeditor` and then `drush en ckeditor -y` and cleared cache again but for some reason the rich text editors still appear completely blank.

I checked the chrome inspector console for errors and found that the site is still looking in the /sites/all/ sub-directories for the module.

```
/sites/all/modules/custom/custom_cke_plugin/ckeditor/custom_cke_plugin/plugin.js?t=DAED Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

ckeditor.js?nviice:219 Uncaught [CKEDITOR.resourceManager.load] Resource name "nyuslink" was not found at "/sites/all/modules/custom/custom_cke_plugin/ckeditor/custom_cke_plugin/plugin.js?t=DAED".
```

Has anyone had issues with moving CKEditor module and found any resolution?

Comment: in Drupal admin CK editor settings u need to update the path, its probably still trying to read from sites/all. Sorry im on mobile, cant provide proper answer.

Comment: Are you using the WYSIQIG module + CKEditor library or are you using the CKEditor module (https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor)?

Comment: CKEditor module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `yourwebsite.com/admin/config/content/ckeditor/editg`

In there you probably need to change the path to ckeditor. As you can see from the screen shot the `%m` stands for `/sites/all/modules/ckeditor`

so you need to erase `%m/ckeditor` and instead put `/sites/default/modules/ckeditor/ckeditor`

**Click image to enlarge**

[image]

Comment: In addition to updating this I also had to update a feature which had configuration for a custom ckeditor plugin module I had built and forgotten about.  The configuration still referred to sites/all/ instead of sites/default/.